# Orchard caching on server

Tags: c#, caching, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am using Orchard CMS version 1.7.3
To implement caching, I am using Orchard's ICacheManager (Get method provided by this interface).

I have one question, does this ICacheManager interface, generates the cache on server for every request? For example, 
-User 1 hits page A. Cache is generated. User 1 hits page again, cached version is displayed.
-User 2 hits page A after User 1. Now would new cache will be generated for User 2 or cache generated by User 1 would be utilized for User 2 as well?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in Orchard, I've observed that the caching manager applies to all users. This means you should be cautious about generating cached results for user based data.

Comment: Thanks for your response @damanptyltd
I also noticed that even if cache is generated, the CPU utilization is quite high while hitting a cached page.

Comment: A "cached page" and a page that has code that uses the ICacheManager are different. CPU usage on a page that implements the ICacheManager is likely to still be high as the rest of the page and all the orchard overhead is not cached, just the sections that are cached with the cache manager. If you use the inbuilt output cache you will see lower CPU utilization as the entire call to that page is cached.

Comment: Hey @damanptyltd,
the output cache module enabled. I am profiling my site and I notice massive number of sql calls to fetch information such as Title or Autoroute (url). I am not doing anything fancy, I am using Orchard's IContentManager interface service to fetch data. However, I am unable to wrap my head around as to why such high CPU utilization.

Comment: All my current projects are on Orchard 1.9.1 so I cannot test if this is normal functionality or indeed a bug with 1.7.3 - are you able to update your orchard to the latest public release and retest the issue? Apologies for the late reply.

Comment: Hey @damanptyltd
I did upgrade to 1.9.2 and caching works really well. Therefore, I believe it is version 1.7.3 that had the problem.

Comment: Great, I'm glad your issue is resolved. If you believe my answer has helped you to your solution, can you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: would definitely do, only if I had enough reputation. I need to have reputation of 15 to do so....I only have 12 right now.